# How to display images horizontally in flatlist react native?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to display feed images horizontally instead of vertically in using FlatList How can I do that? I tried wrapping feed images into a view and then giving it a flex-direction row I also tried to give horizontal={true} to my FlatList but all these methods are not working Can anyone help please to do that?

I created a small app using my code you can access the code from here https://codesandbox.io/s/runtime-leaf-jywqqr?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1):

`horizontal` works just fine, here is the simple example:

```
const Photo = ({download_url}) => (
  <Image style={{width: 320, height: 180}} source={{uri: download_url}} />
);

const App = () => {
  const [photos, setPhotos] = useState([])
  useEffect(() => {
    const getPhotos = async () => {
        const response = await fetch("https://picsum.photos/v2/list")
        if (response.ok) {
          setPhotos(await response.json())
        }
    }
    getPhotos()
  }, [])
  return (
    <FlatList
      data={photos}
      horizontal
      renderItem={({item}) => <Photo download_url={item.download_url} />}
      keyExtractor={item => item.id}
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: I tried doing that and it's working horizontally but it's also scrolling horizontally in one row only how can I make 3 photos in each row,

Any idea about it

Comment: So what you are actually looking for is grid view with 3 columns?

Comment: yes but all horizontally

Answer (score 0):

I think you need set width, height for item